# Saving data to the console using javascript, jquery, underscore and templating

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, underscore.js-templating

I'm trying to save data into localStorage, but JavaScript stops functioning. I've unsuccessfully used underscore to put out my information with templating.

Here is my code:

```
function Book(title, author, release_date, image) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.release_date = release_date;
    this.image = image;

    this.items = localStorage.getItem("books");
    this.key = "books";
}

function SaveRender() {}

SaveRender.prototype.saveToLs = function(obj) {
    if (this.items) {
        items_json = JSON.parse(this.items);
    } else {
        items_json = [];
    }

    items_json.push(obj);

    localStorage.setItem(this.key, JSON.stringify(items_json));
}

SaveRender.prototype.renderTemplate = function(template_source, where) {
    var items_json = JSON.parse(this.items);

    var template = _.template($(template_source).html());

    _.each(items_json, function(item) {
        $(where).append(template(item));
    });
}

Book.prototype = new SaveRender();
Book.prototype.constructor = Book;

var myBook = new Book("Arun's Book", "Arun Sood", "Today", "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-qJA7dW3W-M0/VH4l2LQUIEI/AAAAAAAAACo/ZJqeqHgpmBs/s1600/books.png");
myBook.saveToLs(myBook);

myBook.renderTemplate("#book-template", "#book-container");
```

Comment: You should include the error you're seeing. And preferably study those lines of code and try to debug them yourself.